# make a call from the twilio number to my phone and stream in real time the audio of my phone

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I want to create a bot that will make calls based on DB of customers I have and sell to them the new service I offer. the idea is to call to them, pitch them the new service and ask if they are interested, getting the audio of their answers and using VAD algorithm (Voice Activity detection) and speech to text, translate the response of the user to text then filter words of positive and negative (e.g Yes, I'm interested, No, dont need that) and then based on that I could answer accordingly and with time and development progress a real talk with my customer.

Now, I wondering if it's possible to do it with twilio? and if so how?
is there a way to make call from my twilio number and stream the audio of the receiver to my server?
do I need to make conference room put the twilio number and the customer them, stream the audio of the receiver and pass it to the twilio number? other better way? I tried to do it but could not make it and chatGPT was not helpful at all, and also could not find any useful tutorial :(

Comment: The short answer is YES. It's definitely possible with [media streams](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/stream).